# font awesome icons are not showing angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I have used ngx-tree-select for multi-level-selection.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-tree-select

Inside dropdown font awesome icons are not showing. When inspect, . font awesome version which I had is "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.2.0", and I also installed latest version "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.0", but still icons are not showing inside dropdown.

[image]

plus,minus,check icons nothing showing. Can someone help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: have you seen the index.html? `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I tried with this import in html and tried still I could not see icon

Comment: are the fa icons working outside of the dropdown & are there any errors in console - specifically the n/w call to load the fa css file

Comment: No errors in console. but after import in index.html also icons are not showing inside dropdown as well outside box. <i class="fa fa-square"></i> can view but <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> can't show

Comment: https://ngx-tree-select-njvqck.stackblitz.io - try this. have downloaded the css file locally and referred it in angular.json

Comment: I tried but compilation is getting failed. created one file name as "font-awesome.min.css" and imported in angular.json "./src/font-awesome-5.min.css"

Comment: Not sure what I am missing.probably its a small mistake but struggling for longtime

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping me. I found the fix for this,

I have imported
"  
"
in index.html and few css addition in styles.css

```
tree-select-item .item.item a span .fa {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
tree-select-item .item.item a .fa {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

As my application, have default `.fa { font-family:"Font awesome 5 free"}` this not allowed to show older icons.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation [here](https://fontawesome.com/v3.2.1/get-started/)

Add in your head section in  `index.html`

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```